# Is there a way to detect and fix mapped function keys in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bios

In my application, we use function keys, like <kbd>F2</kbd>, for keyboard shortcuts. But on some computers, the function keys are mapped to system functions, like volume mute, or increase brightness, and you have to hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> if you want <kbd>F2</kbd>.

My software is a line of business application that the users *must* use to do their job, but they are freelancers who use their own, miscellaneous hardware AND are relatively non-technical.

I know that this could be changed in the BIOS or via various OEM tools, but most users don't have the skills to do this, and the variety of possible hardware and BIOS utilities makes it hard to send universal instructions.

We *do* actually have remote control software on the machine, and could change something in Windows, but not something in the BIOS, unless accessible from Windows.

So the question is: is there any way to access the needed keyboard mapping in a universal way from Windows, so that the app could handle shortcuts properly, or at least a way to write a little utility, to be run as an admin, that would let the user approve a change to the system that would cause the keyboard to behave in the needed way?

Comment: The Fn key operates at the keyboard hardware level. Windows doesn't even see it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I'm honored to receive your reply. I don't need to see the `Fn` key as such, I just need to know that they pressed `F2`, with or without it. Is there no hardware agnostic way to detect the physical `F2` key press, even if this is actually interpreted by the machine as "Volume Mute" or whatever?

Comment: If the Fn key is pressed, then the keyboard doesn't send an F2 to Windows. It sends a VK_VOLUME_MUTE or whatever. Windows has no clue that the VK_VOLUME_MUTE secretly has "F2" printed on it.